# Find out size of UDP datagram BEFORE reading it into buffer?

Tags: c++, udp, posix, datagram, recvfrom

I would like to receive whole UDP datagrams of arbitrary size and put the bytes into a buffer. However, before I allocate the buffer, I need to find out the size of the datagram. Unfortunately, I cannot find an example of this being done anywhere, no do any answers on StackOverflow seem to address this fully.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
sockaddr_in senderAddress;
memset(&senderAddress, 0, sizeof(senderAddress));
socklen_t senderAddressLen = sizeof(senderAddress);
ssize_t datagramLength = recvfrom(udpSocket, nullptr, 0, MSG_PEEK, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&senderAddress), &senderAddressLen);
```

Unfortunately, this always returns zero, even when `recvfrom()` with an actual provided buffer would return nonzero bytes.

It occurred to me that maybe the length argument to `recvfrom()` might be the problem, but changing it to a larger value just causes `recvfrom()` to return an error, specifically "Bad address". This is probably due to the fact that the data pointer being passed is null.

There are other possible ways do to this, but they seem inconsistent across systems as to what they return. Consider the [last comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448408/).

There's another question where someone asked about this ([Receive an entire UDP datagram, regardless of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411131/)), but the explanation is very brief, and it doesn't work for me, even if I include `MSG_TRUNC`.

Another question ([know udp packet size with poll select or epoll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076165/)) mentions using `MSG_PEEK`, but it doesn't fully address the question, and it seems to assume you want to peek at the data.

I don't actually want to peek at the data. I only want to find out the length then allocate a buffer then read the data into it. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Note: Although I plan to run this on Linux, I'm doing my prototyping on a Mac. `MSG_TRUNC` seems to be defined, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: MSG_PEEK should work with a null buffer pointer. You could just allocate 65507 bytes. It will always be enough, generally far more than enough. Memory is cheap.

Comment: UDP  datagrams are relatively small (less than 64KiB) so perhaps it's easier to just allocate 64KiB than to first figure out how much to allocate?

Comment: Memory is cheap on MOST systems. However, I'm writing this particular project to work on some embedded processors too, so I'm doing a lot of things to conserve on memory usage.

Comment: OK so 1500 bytes then, or 1460 or whatever the MTU was in one of your linked questions. The practical limit for datagrams without fragmentation is 534 bytes.

Comment: The first Q&A you link appears to show a viable technique, but it uses `MSG_TRUNC`, which is Linux-specific.  I don't think POSIX defines a portable way to determine the message size without providing a buffer at least that size.

Comment: Yes. For now, I've set the buffer size initially to 1500, and it works. But I'd be astonished to find out there's no way to query available bytes the way there is for TCP and other data sources.

Comment: How do you think you can query available bytes for TCP?  Or more accurately, what makes you think that's even a sensible question for TCP?  TCP is stream oriented, so the most you can hope to get is a number of bytes available for immediate reception, but that has little or no semantic significance.

Comment: On Linux, you can use `MSG_TRUNC|MSG_PEEK` to return the size of the datagram even when it was truncated due to the buffer being too small.

Comment: For TCP, you can use `ioctl(tcpSocket, FIONREAD, &availableBytes);`, which will return the number of bytes readable without blocking. I am aware that TCP is stream-oriented. I was just using this as an analogy for what I want to accomplish with UDP.

Comment: Without `MSG_TRUNC` the read/recv call will return the number of bytes written into the buffer -- so when the buffer is too small it just returns the size of the buffer, not the size of the packet

Comment: In fact not, @user207421.  See [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html). The name is a bit mismatched, but `MSG_TRUNC` tells `recv()` to return the size of the *whole* message, even if it was truncated.  (And if it was truncated then you know how many bytes you received in that case -- the specified buffer size).

Comment: @TimothyMiller But it isn't the same thing. "Available to read without blocking" does not mean "message size". `recvmsg()` *blocks* until a datagram is available, with or without MSG_PEEK. In the circumstance where it had to block, FIO_NREAD would have returned zero.

Comment: I'm testing my code on my Mac (for now). MSG_TRUNC seems to be defined, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @user207421 I'm using poll to wake when events occur on multiple file descriptors. One is for the UDP socket. So I'm only going to try to read a datagram when poll tells me there's read data available, and I want to read the whole thing.

Comment: BTW MSG_TRUNC is mentioned in Stevens *TCP/IP Illustrated,*, so it is part of BSD, but he only describes it as an output value in the flags word for `recvmsg()`, not as an input.

Comment: Waking up when a datagram arrives, finding the size, _dynamically allocating_ the buffer and then reading into it is a horrible idea from a performance perspective. If you really need to avoid slack allocation, you can read into a big arena and only increase the write offset when you know how many bytes arrived

Comment: @Useless I totally agree that it would be a best to maintain a persistent buffer and only enlarge it if I need more space. The challenge is in finding out how much more space I need if I get a datagram that is larger than the biggest one so far.

Comment: @TimothyMiller Surely you have a protocol specification that defines the messages? Just use the size of the largest message, or +1 so if you get one that size you know it's a protocol error.

Comment: @user207421 I'm designing the specification. I could, for example, specify the length in a header, read the header, and then read the rest, but as far as I am able to determine, recvfrom will truncate and throw away any bytes I don't read in the first call.

Comment: No, you can't do that. It will indeed throw away what you didn't read. And you can't send the length ahead of the payload in a prior datagram, as there is no sequencing guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Find out size of UDP datagram BEFORE reading it into buffer?

POSIX does not define any way to do this.  You present and refer to potential techniques using `ioctl()`, but POSIX does not define any ioctls other than for STREAMS files (not to be confused with C streams or stream-oriented socket protocols). You also refer to a technique involving passing the `MSG_TRUNC` flag to `recv()` or `recvfrom()`, but

1. `MSG_TRUNC` is not documented by POSIX, and
2. Even if it gives access to the untruncated size, as it does on Linux, you should expect it to return that *together with* the (possibly truncated) message, so not before reading the message into the buffer.

   - But if `recv()` / `recvfrom()` accepts it at all, you should be able to combine `MSG_TRUNC` with `MSG_PEEK` to avoid consuming the message, so that you can make a second round trip to receive the whole message into a large enough buffer.  This will work on Linux, but not necessarily on other POSIX platforms.

Overall, there is really little call for a capability such as you request because in general, UDP applications have built-in, application-specific upper bounds on the datagram size they use.  So NOT

> receive whole UDP datagrams of arbitrary size

, which is not really a thing.

At worst, the maximum payload size the UDP protocol is capable of representing is slightly less than 64 KiB, so if you don't want to impose any other limit then you can at least rely on that.

> before I allocate the buffer, I need to find out the size of the datagram

If by "allocate" you mean *dynamically* allocate, then you would probably be better off just using a large-enough automatic array instead.  Where "large enough" means sufficient to accommodate the largest datagram the application supports, which cannot exceed 64 KiB, but might be limited to something much less.  There are cases where you might want to make a dynamically allocated copy, but even then, the extra allocation and copy might still outperform an extra syscall.

> Note: Although I plan to run this on Linux, I'm doing my prototyping on a Mac. `MSG_TRUNC` seems to be defined, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

If you want something that works on both Mac and Linux then you probably do want to limit yourself to features specified by POSIX.  That very much puts you in the "[no] define[d] way to do this" category.  As described above, your best bet is to receive datagrams into a buffer large enough to accommodate any *valid* message a remote peer could send.

If you need to sacrifice speed for minimal memory consumption then you could dynamically adapt to incoming message size by receiving with `MSG_PEEK`.  If the buffer were completely filled then you would try again with a larger buffer.  Ultimately, you would clear the message from the queue via a call without `MSG_PEEK`.  But note that no variation on dynamic adaptation saves you any memory in practice if the application actually does receive a maximum-size datagram, so I'm not sure this is a problem worth solving.

Comment: One of the platforms I'm planning to port this to is an RP2040, which has 264K of RAM, so allocating a persistent 64K buffer is not feasible. But then again, that is not a POSIX platform and will probably require a totally different implementation for everything. Since I am in control of the protocol, I will just ensure my datagrams are always 1472 bytes or less, and this will solve the problem. Thanks!